# SSL sec_error in 'standalone' web app, full browser ok

Tags: firefox, ssl, firefox-os, html5-apps

I have set up a local webserver in a virtual machine for testing firefox web apps. That server has also been setup as certificate authority to avoid the 'risk messages' for local testing, and i signed a certificate for the webserver.

So, calling the web app in firefox displays no more warnings.

Installing the web app as 'standalone' still displays an alert (messagebox):

> The certificate is not trusted because no certificate issuer chain was provided.
> (Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER)
> (translated by google translator)
>
> Dem Zertifikat wird nicht vertraut, weil keine Zertifikatsausstellerkette angegeben wurde.
> (Fehlercode: sec_error_unknown_issuer)
> (german message)

I am using Apache2.2 and Openssl on debian_wheezy_64 and i think i have done everything allright, can't figure out what the standalone web app is missing with that ssl error message.

**Update:**
As it seems that the standalone web app environment does not know anything about the firefox browser certificates(chain), i configured the webserver (mod_ssl virtualhost) to provide a direct chain to the (self)root ca:

> SSLCertificateChainFile /path_to/ca.crt

Now the problem is, that because maybe the standalone environment does not know the certificate authorities added to firefox, the sec_error know says

> The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is not trusted

I think it makes sense (or no sense...) if the standalone environment has an own certificate management, so the question is, how to tell the standalone environment that i trust the (self)root ca.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the standalone environment with a default trusted certificate chain - "The certificate is not trusted because *no certificate issuer chain was provided*"

When you install Firefox, it comes preconfigured with a set of certificates that it trusts by default. Any certificates whose signature chain terminates at the top with one of these preconfigured certificates will be automatically trusted. For instance, I use opera on windows and by default it trusts a whole host of certificate authorities:
[image: Screenshot of opera's default trusted CA's]

You probably need to configure your standalone environment with a list of default trusted certificate authorities.

Comment: Is it possible that the standalone web app environment does not share the same certificate management with the browser? It seems so, i updated my posting with new research.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was trying to say. To fix your new problem, you can probably edit the chain file to include your self-created certificate authority certificate.

Comment: Actually, there might be some confusion. The browser portion of the standalone environment needs to be configured to trust the self-signed cert. Maybe that wasn't clear :)